# Magento.RestApi behaves different when loaded dynamically from DLL

Tags: c#, rest, magento, async-await

I am using [Magento.RestApi](https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi) in a larger system, where I load the code dynamically from a DLL.

When I use the below code in a stand-alone project, it works fine:

```
private async void dostuff() {
    var client = new MagentoApi()
            .Initialize("<url>", "key", "secret")
            .AuthenticateAdmin("user", "pass");

    var response = await client.GetProductBySku("sku");

    // The response contains the result or errors
    if (!response.HasErrors) {
        var product = response.Result;
        ... do stuff with the result ...
    }
}
```

But, when loaded in the larger project, I get "The request was not successfully completed.", also when trying to catch the error to find the `InnerException` or the stack trace, the debugger doesn't seem to work anymore. Printing out the stack trace gives me:

```
   at Magento.RestApi.MagentoApi.<HandleResponse>d__35`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bart\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SapphireMagentoDriver\SapphireMagentoDriver\MagentoApi.cs:line 445
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Magento.RestApi.MagentoApi.<Execute>d__34`1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bart\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SapphireMagentoDriver\SapphireMagentoDriver\MagentoApi.cs:line 410
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Magento.RestApi.MagentoApi.<GetProductBySku>d__45.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bart\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SapphireMagentoDriver\SapphireMagentoDriver\MagentoApi.cs:line 708
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Magento.RestApi.SapphireMagentoDriver.<DoDownloadArticles>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Users\bart\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SapphireMagentoDriver\SapphireMagentoDriver\DriverInterface.cs:line 103
```

I had to compile the `Magento.RestApi` from source, as the NuGet package uses a different `NewtonSoft.Json` package than my large project. This works fine in the stand alone version.

Comment: is that `async void dostuff` method just a piece of test code or is it actually used in your project?

Comment: @Noseratio it is in the code, because of the `await`. I am quite new to asynchronous programming, but I have tried also without all that stuff, and the same thing happens.

Comment: @Noseratio, I read your comment wrong. Yes, it is test code. I put some code in the main project, which didn't work and I narrowed it down to just this.